# Correct way to combine 95% confidence interval bounds returned by a fitting routine with several measurements?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, fitting, measurement-error, error-propagation

I am looking for someone to just confirm / double-check something for me with regards to errors on measurements.

Let's say I am trying to determine the slope of a relationship by varying one quantity and measuring another, and then I plot the graph and do a least-squares fit straight line to the data (graph on the left). Then I repeat this procedure twice more, to get the middle and right-most graphs.
[image]

Each fit routune will typically give me back a slope and the corresponding 95% confidence interval, so that I obtain $(m_1\pm\Delta m_1), (m_2\pm\Delta m_2)$ and $(m_3\pm\Delta m_3)$. Now I know that the underlying quantity which determines $m$ in each case is the same, so I should be able to quote a best estimate for the slope as their mean

$$
\bar{m} = \frac{m_1+m_2+m_3}{3}. \tag{1}
$$

My question is about the appropriate way to quote the error. We know that for a function $f(x,y)$ with errors in $x$ and $y$ given by $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, respectively, the error on $f$ is given by

$$
\Delta f = \sqrt{ (\Delta x)^2 \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg)^2 +  (\Delta y)^2 \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)^2 }  \tag{2}
$$

So I would think I can determine the error in $\bar{m}$ to be

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta \bar{m} &= \sqrt{ (\Delta m_1)^2 \bigg(\frac{\partial \bar{m}}{\partial m_1}\bigg)^2 +  (\Delta m_2)^2 \bigg(\frac{\partial \bar{m}}{\partial m_2}\bigg)^2  +  (\Delta m_3)^2 \bigg(\frac{\partial \bar{m}}{\partial m_3}\bigg)^2} \tag{3}  \\ 
&= \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{ (\Delta m_1)^2 + (\Delta m_2)^2 + (\Delta m_3)^2 } \tag{4} 
\end{align}
$$

First question, is this correct?

Second question, is it okay to propagate 95% confidence intervals in this way? Should I simply quote now the result as $\bar{m} \pm \Delta \bar{m}$ and just explain that $\Delta \bar{m}$ is the combined 95% confidence interval, or should I convert the 95% number from the fits into standard errors (through the factor of [1.96](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96))?

Thanks in advance,

(I am for now assuming Gaussian errors everywhere.)

---

**EDIT**

It was suggested in the comments that I first implement weighting in the averaging step before worrying about the errors. This should help to give more weight to slopes which have tighter confidence intervals (and vice versa).

According to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting#Context), the weighted version of the mean would be given by
$$
\bar{m}_\textrm{w} = \frac{\sum_i w_i m_i}{\sum_iw_i}, \hspace{1cm} \textrm{where} \hspace{0.5cm} w_i = \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\tag{5}
$$
and $\sigma_i$ is the variance of each slope. Therefore, in my case with the three example slopes, it should be
$$
\bar{m}_\textrm{w} = \frac{m_1/\sigma_1^2 + m_2/\sigma_2^2 + m_3/\sigma_3^2}{1/\sigma_1^2 + 1/\sigma_2^2 + 1/\sigma_3^2}. \tag{6}
$$

The variance on the weighted mean slope is given at the above [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting#Context) again by
$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{Var}(\bar{m}_\textrm{w}) &= \frac{\sum_iw_i^2\sigma_i^2}{\big( \sum_iw_i\big)^2}\tag{7}\\
&= \frac{1/\sigma_1^2 + 1/\sigma_2^2 + 1/\sigma_3^2}{\big(1/\sigma_1^2 + 1/\sigma_2^2 + 1/\sigma_3^2\big)^2}\tag{8}\\
&= \big(1/\sigma_1^2 + 1/\sigma_2^2 + 1/\sigma_3^2\big)^{-1}.\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$

So now my main question remains - these are variances, so should we convert the 95% confidence intervals $\Delta m_i$ returned by a fitting algorithm somehow into a variance?

Maybe for a concrete example we could imagine the following values were returned from the fitting routine:
$$
\begin{align}
m_1 &= 5.5\; (4.9, 6.1)\rightarrow \Delta m_1 = 0.6\\
m_2 &= 5.5\; (5.3, 5.7)\rightarrow \Delta m_2 = 0.2\\
m_3 &= 5.2\; (4.5, 5.9)\rightarrow \Delta m_3 = 0.7
\end{align}
$$
where the values in brackets represent the 95% confidence intervals. How should the estimate of the slope be reported, including errors? Let's imagine I only have access to these values (and not the underlying data that was used for fitting to obtain these slopes).

Comment: You can improve things using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was not too concerned about weighting them here, because I am assuming they contribute in a similar way (ofcourse I didn't make that clear in the OP). I am more asking about how to handle the 95% numbers that are returned from a OLS algorithm.

Comment: To first order, you handle the confidence intervals by using them to weight your estimate, as indicated by @Jarle.  Only then can you construct a reasonable confidence interval for that estimate.

Comment: Thanks both, I have edited the question to try to incorporate your advice.

Comment: I would question whether combining the fits is sensible - instead, I would formulate a model that will use all of the data together, will have separate intercepts (and possibly sigma or other parameters) for each subset, but the same slope for each subset. Then you'll get your 95% interval straightforwardly by fitting this model. Is there some reason why this is not an option? (e.g. you only have access to summaries of the fit, but not the underlying data)

Comment: Yes exactly, I only have access to $m_i \pm \Delta m_i$ where $\Delta m_i$ is the 95% interval.

Comment: Does "experiment" refer to a single datapoint, or to a collection of datapoints which contribute to each fit? Or "measurement" is a single datapoint?

Comment: Are your experiments/runs supposed to have different variance in the noise? Or can we can we consider the process to be the same in which case we can use [pooled variance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance).

Comment: Each experiment/run has a different variance (let's say for example that the instrument which collected the measurements was not the same for each run, and some instruments are better than others). I do not know the underlying measurements, but I can see from the 95% confidence limits that some measurements have tighter intervals than others.

Comment: @teeeeee But doesn't that mean that the variance in the slope from run to run, is neither the same for those instruments? What are those confidence intervals indicating? Are they the confidence interval for the estimate of the slope in a specific run or for the estimate of the slope overall. My problem with trying to get the concept of your multiple values is that it is unclear to me whether you consider multiple sources of error, and whether the confidence intervals reflect all those sources or not.

Comment: Yes they are the confidence intervals for the slope in the particular run. I would like to combine them to get an estimate of the mean slope (i.e slope changes slowly over time, and I would like to know its average value, which I did using weighted average). I would also like to know then, for any given slope that I measure, what is the spread of the distrubution I can expect. I don't know what the sources of error are - only that I can assume them to be Gaussian, and know the 95% bounds on each one.

Comment: With source of error I did not expect a specific answer about the exact source, but more about the character of the source of the error. The problem might be that you pool data and estimate the variance/error based on wrong specified error estimates (error estimates which only refer to the error within the study but not the error relating to external validity). See for instance literature about forest plots and heterogeneity https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1767262/ .

Comment: In the end, you should make a weighted mean of the studies, but the weights do not need to be solely based on the confidence intervals (those intervals often only reflect the error due to the distribution of measurement errors within the study, ie the residuals, but the study might have some systematic error). A study with a small confidence interval might still have a large error. It will depend on the heterogeneity.

Comment: Yes I understand, I am considering only statistical error here, and neglect systematics - just to learn how to handle this simple case. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Systematical errors can also vary in a statistical way. The issue is whether the variation in the slope is only due to the measurement error or whether there is some additional variation in the slope from run to run. E.g. if those slopes are growth rate of bacteria (and you determine this by sampling at different times in a particular batch), then the growth rate in a specific run might be accurately determined by taking many measurements in a single run/batch. But from run to run (different batches) you will get a different slope each time.

Comment: Different way of trying to understand your problem/case. If you had the underlying data, how would you perform the regression? Would you use a mixed effects model or not?

Comment: Yes okay. Let's say I have x3 pots of bacteria and they each have slighly different growth rates. Within each pot the growth rate is constant, and I can accurately determine the growth rate in each pot by taking more and more measurements ($\Delta m_i$ would be reduced). The error on these datapoints is given by the instrumentation. The 3 growth rates obtained would be my $m_i$ from above. Then I decide I would like to know the mean growth rate $\bar{m}$, along with an estimation of the error.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why on earth would you want to average? Just pool the data for $m_i, i=1,2,3$, regress on pooled dataset and return CI. You know from Markov theorem that averaging (or anything else) is inferior to pooling data.

Comment: You understand I only have access to the three numbers along with their confidence intervals, right? Not the underlying data to be able to pool it. How exactly would you recommend operating on the three numbers I gave in the question, along with their three respective confidence intervals?

Comment: @teeeeee Got it. You should have tagged me, though (otherwise I could have easily missed your comment). See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine the 95% confidence intervals come from some assumptions on normality of data. Otherwise, please state how you got these CI. This implies you believe the mean of each slope (viewed as a RV) is $m_i$ with some variance $\sigma_i$
In this case you can average the slopes as you did and get the new variance of the averaged estimator (assuming independent errors). From said variance you can get 95% CI (using 1.96 standard deviations).

So, to summarize (assuming $m_i$ are independent is crucial):

1. Let $m := \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^N m_i \sigma_i^{-2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^{-2}}$
2. Let $\sigma^2 := Var(m) = Var(\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^N m_i \sigma_i^{-2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^{-2}}) = (\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^{-2}})^2 \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma^{-4}Var(m_i) = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^{-2}}$.
3. Note that this is the harmonic mean! Finally you see it in the wild after learning that [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities) in your first calculus class!!
4. A 95% CI for the true value of the slope is $[m- 1.96\sigma, m+ 1.96\sigma]$ (see [1.96](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96))

Comment: Just to check - these are exactly the same as the formulae I quoted in the question, right?

Comment: @teeeeee  Yes they are (you wrote so much text I got lazy reading and decided it's easier to just post an answer). Note that you are relying on $m_i$'s being independent - you did not mention that anywhere and that is an assumption you are implicitly making.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to offer in terms of methods, I think the ones presented here (esp inverse variance weighted approaches) are good ones.  What I can add is a small simulation study to prove that under the assumption of Gaussian errors in the regression, this process has good enough coverage

```r
set.seed(0)

library(tidyverse)

simulate_data<-function(n){
  x = rnorm(n)
  y = 2*x + 1 + rnorm(n, 0, 0.5)
  model = lm(y~x)
  results = tibble(beta = coef(model)['x'],
                   w = 1/vcov(model)['x','x'])
}




simulate_procedure<-function(iter){
  
  n =  rnbinom(3,200,0.9)
  
  results = map_dfr(n, simulate_data)
  
  m = sum(results$beta*results$w)/sum(results$w)
  
  sig = sqrt(1/sum(results$w))
  
  interval = tibble(lower = m - 1.96*sig, 
                    est = m, 
                    upper = m + 1.96*sig)
  
  
  interval
}


map_dfr(1:10000, simulate_procedure, .id = 'iter')  %>% 
  mutate(contains = (2<upper)&(2>lower)) %>% 
  summarise(mean(contains))

>>>0.922
```

So what does this mean?  It means that were I to repeat this procedure to construct a 95% interval for the slope, the resulting interval would capture the true slope (here 2) only 92% of the time.  So barring I didn't make a mistake (entirely possible) that seems to be good enough.

> How should the estimate of the slope be reported, including errors? Let's imagine I only have access to these values (and not the underlying data that was used for fitting to obtain these slopes).

So I would compute $m$ and $\sigma^2$ as mentioned by Yair Daon.  You don't need to access the data in order to do these.  In your example, the $m$ would be 5.5, 5.5, 5.2.  The variances are found by doing a little algebra on the confidence interval.   Remember, confidence intervals look like

$$m \pm 1.96 se $$

Here, $se$ is the standard error (or the standard deviation of the sampling distribution).  You can find the variance by taking the difference between interval endpoints and then dividing by $3.92 = 2\times 1.96$.  Your sigmas (not squared) would then be 0.306, 0.102, 0.357.

So your best estimate for $m$ from the example you've provided is 5.47, with an accompanying interval of 5.29 to 5.66.  These were computed using the formulae provided by Yair.

Comment: Can you explain a little what the code is doing? I am not familiar with the programming language you have used. Thanks!

Comment: @teeeeee . I'm basically simulating your example 10,000 times and seeing how many times the confidence interval captures the true parameter of interest.